# Comma Splice rules or exceptions

Tags: grammar, commas

Are these all considered comma splices. I wasn't sure as they refer back to the clause before the comma directly as apposed to just similar ideas. In which case a semi-colon would be used.

Any exceptions to this rule.

Space: What it is, what it isn't.

Every time I close my eyes I remember his laughter, his infectious smile.

I won't win it, I just want to get through it.

Comment: *Space: what it is, what it isn't* isn't really a complete sentence anyway, but more like a headline, so you can't really say that it is or isn't a comma splice.

Comment: They are arguably comma splices. You could avoid any ambiguity if you added a conjunction to each. But note that even though comma splices are syntactically unsound, they can still be stylistically acceptable and understood.

Answer (score 1):

A comma splice is a flaw in punctuation, but not a grammar mistake. If two complete sentences are joined with a comma we call it a comma splice.

The first one is a headline, it consists of three noun phrases "Space", "what it is" and "what it isn't".  There isn't a complete sentence here, so it can't be a comma splice. A comma is fine, a semicolon is fine too if you prefer.

The second also doesn't join two complete sentences: "his infectious smile" can't be a sentence. What you have is basically a list of thing that are remembered, and lists are usually separated by commas

The third does have two complete sentences, and so it is a comma splice. These look to me like complete sentences. I would use a full stop:

> I won't win it. I just want to get through it.